# How to implement a vertically stretchable fullscreen layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a full-screen layout in which the content will adjust to the size of the footer.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.layout__content {
  height: 100%;
  
  align-self: stretch;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: green;
}

.content__text {
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
  <main class='layout__content'>
    <div class='content'>
      <text class='content__text'>Here be dragons</text>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class='footer' />
</div>
```

As you can see, if you change the value of `height` in `.footer`, then the content will fill all the space remaining from the footer. Everything works as intended.

Now I'm trying to make another layout. If the total height of the content and footer does not exceed `100vh`, this display is similar to what was previously. But if it surpasses due to the content height, then a scroll should appear.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.layout__content {
  height: 100%;
  
  align-self: stretch;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: green;
}

.content__text {
  height: 150vh;
  
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
  <main class='layout__content'>
    <div class='content'>
      <text class='content__text'>Here be dragons</text>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class='footer' />
</div>
```

In the example, the text was `150vh` long. **But the problem is if this value will be removed, the content will collapse.**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.layout__content {
  height: 100%;
  
  align-self: stretch;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: green;
}

.content__text {
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
  <main class='layout__content'>
    <div class='content'>
      <text class='content__text'>Here be dragons</text>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class='footer' />
</div>
```

Notes:

1. I want to change attributes only of `layout` and `layout__content`.
2. `footer` may have any height, so it is impossible to just hardcode `height`, `min-height`, `max-height` etc in the other elements. In the example it was hardcoded to `20vh`, but it is only in the example.

I've already tried the following things:

- `layout` - `height: 1px;`
- `layout-content` - `min-height: inherit`;
- `layout-content` - `min-height: 100%`;

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved this with double-dimensional flex-grow:

Content `content__text` is short:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.layout {
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.layout__content {
    flex-grow: 1;

    display: flex;

    background-color: blue;
}

.layout__content-wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    background-color: green;
}

.content__text {
    background-color: white;
}

.footer {
    flex-grow: 0;
    height: 20vh;

    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
    <main class='layout__content'>
        <div class="layout__content-wrapper">
            <div class='content'>
                <text class='content__text'>Here be dragons</text>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class='footer'/>
</div>
```

Same code, but `content__text` is long:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.layout {
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.layout__content {
    flex-grow: 1;

    display: flex;

    background-color: blue;
}

.layout__content-wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    background-color: green;
}

.content__text {
    /* Demonstration */
    height: 200vh;
    
    background-color: white;
}

.footer {
    flex-grow: 0;
    height: 20vh;

    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
    <main class='layout__content'>
        <div class="layout__content-wrapper">
            <div class='content'>
                <text class='content__text'>Here be dragons</text>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class='footer'/>
</div>
```